# MySQL via Python module installed or not?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

When I try to connect to MySQL via Python I encounter following issue "**No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package**". I have successfully installed the required modules and still getting this error?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this error to occur. I had named the Python file to **mysql** which was causing the error to happen.